# Extract template parameter from Generic type

Tags: typescript

I know how to extract `string` from `string[]` but this is giving me a headache:

```
type bla<T = number> = 123;

// given just "bla", how can I extract the template parameter "number" in this case?

type T = bla extends bla<infer U> ? U : never;
```

I think this wasn't possible 4 years ago but maybe something has changed.

Comment: "I think this wasn't possible 4 years ago." Could you tell us where you got that from? I enjoy doing research but if you have some recollection of this being discussed before it would be helpful to look at that discussion

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I just remember I played around it when I started with TS and I was told this wasn't possible. So it's just memories, sorry. :( I should probably remove this sentence from my post as it does contribute nothing.

Comment: The particular example is problematic because `bla<T>` is `123` for all `T`, and [inference from unused generics isn't generally possible](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--).  If your type actually *used* `T` then we could look into it more.

Comment: You're my hero. Sadly I can't accept comments. ^^

Comment: I would write up an answer, but I see someone already jumped in here and wrote it up with a link to the same faq entry. I'll give them the benefit of the doubt that they did this independently, I guess.

Comment: Just post an answer and I will accept yours. ;D (already ignored the copy cat answer below ^^)

Comment: Okay I'll do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem here is that your [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter is unused:

```
type Foo<T = number> = 123;
type Oops = Foo extends Foo<infer U> ? U : never;
// type Oops = unknown
```

Here `Foo<T>` is going to be `123` for any `T` whatsoever.  TypeScript's type system is supposed to be [structural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) and not [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system).  So without a structural dependence on `T`, inference of `T` from `Foo<T>` will not be reliable, even if you can get it to work sometimes.  That's why [the TypeScript FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--) discourages any generic types that don't use their type parameters.

---

The next biggest problem is that TypeScript just does not use [default type arguments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) for inference at all, as mentioned in [microsoft/TypeScript#42064](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42064) .

So even if TypeScript types were treated nominally, you might not get the behavior you are looking for.  Compare this to [constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints), which at least participate somewhat in inference:

```
type Bar<T extends number = number> = 123;
type Hmm = Bar extends Bar<infer U> ? U : never;
// type Hmm = number
```

The same argument for `Foo<T>` would imply that `Bar<T>` would also fail to work, but you get `number` instead of `unknown` here.  And that's because the compiler will fall back to the constraint when failing to infer.  So even though `Bar<T>` is `123` for all `T`, there's still a `number` constraint on `T` that can be used.

---

Put both of those together and it means that what you're doing isn't possible. You'd need to refactor to use the type parameter and then be sure to explicitly mention the type without a type argument to get the compiler to substitute in the default, and only then would it be likely that you could infer the type properly.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAFSgXigOwK4FsBGEATgHzpQCMATAMwDcAUKJFAPJxgDO58cUEAD2ARMAE269EAS0wAzYlACqZAPxKoALiwQAbsUYB6A1GbR2XctkwBrTHADumBk3DQAQgEMiKfkJHisPEIichwCYjIManoXFgAJXFxyTxDBYTFuFOk5BWUoNUVNbT0iQ2NTKASkjDDg5yA)

Comment: Thank you Typescript god. Really appreciate the help you provide to the TS community here, as well as on github!