# Infer Template parameter from Interface?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Check the following code:

```js
interface B<T> {
  bla?: T;
}

class A implements B<string> {
}

type thisShouldBeString = A extends B<infer T> ? T : never;
```

I want to infer string from A. Is that possible? How?

Edith: This is my other approach that didn't work:

```
interface B<T> {
  bla?: T;
}

class A implements B<string> {
}

type thisShouldBeString = A extends { bla?: infer T } ? T : never;
```

Comment: I may be wrong here but the first approach you provided is correct and should `infer` string from `A`.

Comment: An `implements` clause doesn't affect the type of the class, [it's just a check](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23885#issuecomment-386488212).  And therefore `A` is just `class A {}` and has no structural dependency on `string`.  If you want that to work you need to actually give it such a dependency as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WvyEMm).  If you can't do something like that then what you're asking for is [impossible](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--).  (continues)

Comment: (continued) Does that fully address the question. If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, go ahead writing an answer. Thanks againe <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to note that [an `implements` clause doesn't actually affect the type of the class to which it's applied](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#cautions).  It's only a *check* that the class adheres to the implemented type, and other than that check everything behaves as if the clause were not there.  So when it comes to type inference,

```
class A implements B<string> { }
```

is exactly the same as

```
class A { }
```

That means `A` just is [an empty class](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely) and you can expect weird things to happen.

In particular, when you try to use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to `infer` a `T` for which `A extends B<T>`, it won't work as desired. If a subtype of `B<T>` doesn't have the `bla` property, then `T` is *unused*, which [prevents inference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--).  `A` is assignable to `B<T>` *for any possible `T`*.  The compiler has no reason to prefer `string` over any other type, so the inference fails and it falls back to [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type):

```
type ThisShouldBeString = A extends B<infer T> ? T : never;
//type ThisShouldBeString = unknown
```

---

In order for this to possibly work, you need make sure that the comparison between `A` and `B<T>` has some *[structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) dependence* on `T`.  For example:

```
class A /* implements B<string> */ {
  declare bla?: string;
}
```

Now `A` has a structure from which it can be meaningfully compared to `B<T>`, even without the `implements` clause (which again, doesn't affect things).  And the inference succeeds:

```
type ThisShouldBeString = A extends B<infer T> ? T : never;
//type ThisShouldBeString = string
```

Hooray!

By the way, this doesn't have anything to do with the version of `A` that's emitted as JavaScript.  Given that I have [`declare`d](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier) the `bla` property, it will not even appear at runtime.  Both versions of `A` will compile to something like `class A {}`.  The difference between them is only in the static type system.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=5.1.6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIB4AqA+ZBvAWAChlkAjAGzgH4AuZTAbmIF9jiEqBnL5AQWTAAtgAcKEIRHC8MXMFFABzXIRLIAJhE5woKSjXpyFIRcyJsixMAE8RKTAAtgXAMoOA9gFcK61BBfySsgAvPzIEAAekCDqMuigMNAMuNQMyPQgEABu0GYA9Hk2dgxOrh7evv6BJiHIRkpAA)

Comment: Thanks again for this amazing answer. I just realised I fell to this some time ago and you already explained the unused problematic to me. ( [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75899051/extract-template-parameter-from-generic-type) ) too bad my brain is too small ;D